# pattern Not Working with dynamicaly appended HTML element

Tags: css, html

I am dynamically creating HTML element and on click of button appending it to the div . My Problem is HTML pattern validation is not working with that ...

```
 var moredetail="<label for='teachername' data-icon='' class='nopostcard'> Teacher\'s Name 
</label> <input type='text' id='teachername' class='nopostcard' required='required' pattern='[A-Za-z]' 
title='TeacherName must be alphanumeric' />";
        moredetail +="<label for='comment' data-icon='' class='nopostcard'> Comments </label>
 <input type='text' id='comment' class='comment nopostcard' required='required'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I am creating button type="button "  for html validation i should have it submit type ,
I have some issues if i use submit . so i got way with button using following code

```
var String = document.getElementById("teachername").value;
var Letters = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]+$/.test(String);

 if(Letters == false)
 {
 alert('Teacher name can be only string');
 return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving length to pattern attribute
for example:

```
 <label for='teachername' data-icon='' class='nopostcard'> Teacher\'s Name </label> 
    <input type='text' id='teachername' class='nopostcard' required='required' 
    pattern='[A-Za-z]{5}' 
    title='TeacherName must be alphanumeric' />
```

this code will check for pattern length of 5 characters